# Unexpected result while dividing int by int and storing result into double

Tags: java, int, double, division

I'm having a weird problem.

This code simply divides an int by another int, stores result in a double variable and prints it:

```
int a = 200;
int b = 557;

double divisionResult = a / b;

System.out.println("Result: " + divisionResult);
```

After executing this code, the output is:

```
Result: 0
```

This is weird, because `200/557` is `0.3590664272890485`

I noticed that if i cast `a` and `b` to `double` in the division line

```
double divisionResult = (double) a / (double) b;
```

It works perfectly.

Why do i have to cast my variables to double to get the real division result?

Comment: That is normal. Result from `int`/`int`=`int`. If you want to change type of result you need to change type of at least one of arguments to floating point like `float` or `double`

Comment: Note that you have to *cast* only one of the two operands to force a *double division*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because in integer division, if the answer is not a perfect integer, the digits after the decimal point will be removed (integer division yields integer value).

Note that you don't have to cast the both integers, you can cast only one, the second will be implicitly converted.

Why after the cast it works?

Because cast has higher precedence than `/`. So first it cast, then it divides. If this were not the case, you would get `0.0`.

Comment: Even if the `cast` had a lower precedence than `/`, the OP's division would still work since the right operand would be casted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As always, any calculation on the right side of the assignment operator is executed before assigning its result to the variable specified on the left side. When the calculation is performed, it is a division between two `int`s, which is an integer division, which (as I'm sure you know), produces an integer result (i.e. a quotient without any remainder). Only after this calculation is performed is the result of the integer division - which is 0 - cast to a double.

As you observed, changing one or both of the `int`s to a double makes the calculation a double division, rather than an integer division.

Answer (score 1):

a is int, and b is int, dividing a/b results an int value so 0.35 converted to int becomes 0.So you have to cast it like

```
double d = (double)a/b;
```

Comment: Note that this only works because the `cast operator` has a higher precedence than the `division operator`, which is not obvious at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

Because the way you are doing it now is like this:

You do an integerdivision on a and b. The result of that is the integer 0. After that you assign the result to a double.

You could just cast either a or b to a double and Java will recognize that and give you a double as a result.